# (Dis-)proving the series $\sum\limits_n\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, self-learning

I am trying to prove that the series:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$

converges.

Now I know that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^n=e$$

But how can I use that knowledge to prove the convergance ?

Intuitively I would say that the series diverges since it doesn't approach zero but how can I formally prove this?

Comment: Usually, "exponential series" denotes $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}.$$

Comment: How can this series converge if every term is greater than $1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A necessary condition for the series
$$
\sum a_j
$$
to converge is $a_j\to0$ as $j\to\infty$. If you can show that $a_j\not\to0$ as $j\to\infty$, then this implies that the series diverges. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) for more details.

Comment: so my proof would sound something like "since $a_j$ is non zero the series cannot converge q.e.d. ?

Comment: @zython "Since $a_j$ is non zero" is ambiguous. We have to be precise. Since $a_j$ does not converge to $0$ as $j\to\infty$, the series diverges. $a_j\to e$ as $j\to\infty$,

Comment: thank you for the correction, I'll accept in a bit

Answer (score 3):

> $Proposition:$ If   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges  then $a_n \rightarrow 0$

$Proof:$

Let $s_n= \sum_{k=1}^na_k$ then from convergence  exists  $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s_n \rightarrow s$

Now we have that $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1} \rightarrow s-s=0$

Use this to derive a contradiction assuming that your series converges.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

For $n>0$

$$\Bigl(1+\frac {1}{n}\Bigr)^n>1$$

and comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

When $n$ is large, $(1+ 1/n)^n \approx e$ so the tail of your series looks like
$$
\cdots e + e + e + \cdots
$$
so can't converge - as you suspected.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima No, it's just a dramatic way to suggest that the general term doesn't approach $0$, implying divergence.

Comment: No problem friend of the world.